# Dúvida sobre Modelagem de Entidade

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, modelagem

Tenho uma entidade chamada Solicitações que satisfaz o seguinte negócio:

1. Uma solicitação é feita por um Funcionário(Entidade), depois a mesma é alterada por outro Funcionário e então confirmada por um terceiro Funcionário.
2. Em uma solicitação estou enviando um Cliente(Entidade) de um Leito(Entidade) para outro Leito(Entidade).
   Segue abaixo o atual mapeamento:

   ```
   using System;
   using SG.ProjetoTCC.Domain.Entities.Local;

   namespace SG.ProjetoTCC.Domain.Entities
   {
       public class Solicitacao
       {
           public Solicitacao()
           {
               SolicitacaoId = Guid.NewGuid();            

           }
           public Guid SolicitacaoId { get; set; }
           public DateTime DataSolicitacao { get; set; }

           public Guid FuncionarioSolicitanteId { get; set; }
           public virtual Funcionario FuncionarioSolicitante { get; set; }

           public TipoSolicitacao TipoSolicitacao { get; set; }
           public Guid ClienteId { get; set; }
           public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

           public Guid LeitoLocalId { get; set; }
           public virtual Leito LeitoLocal { get; set; }

           public Guid LeitoDestinoId { get; set; }
           public virtual Leito LeitoDestino { get; set; }
           public DateTime DataReserva { get; set; }

           public Guid FuncionarioReservaId { get; set; }
           public virtual Funcionario FuncionarioReserva { get; set; }
           public DateTime DataConclusao { get; set; }

           public Guid FuncionarioConclusaoId { get; set; }
           public virtual Funcionario FuncionarioConclusao { get; set; }
           public DateTime Tempo { get; set; }

       }
   }
   ```

   Uma Solicitação não tem muitos(IEnumerable) Funcionários, ela tem 3 funcionários, que são: FuncionarioSolicitante(o que solicitou um leito), FuncionarioReserva(que reservou o leito) e FuncionarioConclusão(que colocou o cliente no Leito destino), e também 2 Leitos; LeitoLocal, e LeitoDestino.
3. Meu design está correto? Eu deveria utilizar uma Collection(Leito) e uma Collection(Funcionario)?

Desculpem se ficou muito confuso, mais acho que dá para entender do jeito que expliquei.

Obrigado,

Abraços.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SamuelGomes, está correta sim.

Estas propriedades é o que chamamos de `Propriedades de Navegação`, elas nos permitem acessar rapidamente uma outra Entidade que está ligada a ela.

Por exemplo, Na Entidade `Solicitacao` temos uma propriedade de navegação chamada `FuncionarioSolicitante`, esta propriedade nos permite acessar rapidamente ao Funcionario que solicitou esta Solicitação. Como cada `Solicitacao` pode possuir apenas 1 Funcinario `Solicitante` então não é necessário que seja uma lista.

Como toda navegação deve permitir o fluxo dos dois lados, a Entidade `Funcionario`deve possuir uma propriedade chamada `SolicitacoesSolicitante`, que permite acessar rapidamente todas as `Solicitacao` que ele realizou. Como um funcionário pode realizar N solicitações, esta propriedade deve ser uma coleção (`DbSet`).

Isto em momento algum impede que o `Funcionario` não possa ser o Solicitante e o Liberador da mesma `Solicitacao`, porém teremos propriedades de navegação distindas, pois são fluxos de navegação distintos.

Normalmente cada `FK` no Banco de Dados dará origem a uma propriedade de Navegação nas entidades envolvidas, como no exemplo abaixo:

**Foreign Keys**

`1:N` `FK_Funcionario_Solicitacao_Solicitante` (1 Funcionario -> N Solicitacao)
`1:N` `FK_Funcionario_Solicitacao_Reserva` (1 Funcionario -> N Solicitacao)
`1:N` `FK_Funcionario_Solicitacao_Conclusao` (1 Funcionario -> N Solicitacao)

**Entidade - Funcionario**

```
public virtual DbSet<Solicitacao> SolicitacoesSolicitante { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Solicitacao> SolicitacoesReserva { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Solicitacao> SolicitacoesConclusao { get; set; }
```

**Entidade - Solicitacao**

```
public virtual Funcionario FuncionarioSolicitante { get; set; }
public virtual Funcionario FuncionarioReserva { get; set; }
public virtual Funcionario FuncionarioConclusao { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sim, eu tenho 3 FKs. Não entendí sua modelagem SolicitaçãoSolicitante, SolicitacoesReserva e SolicitacoesConclusão. Pois em Uma Solicitação eu tenho 3 campos do tipo Funcionario.

Comment: adicionei alumas informações adicionais, talvez lhe ajude a entender melhor.

Comment: Estas propriedades `SolicitacoesSolicitante`, etc... pertencem a entidade `Funcionario` e não a `Solicitante`

Comment: Agora entendí o seu raciocínio. Vc está distinguindo Funcionário entre: Solicitante = Aquele funcionário que somente solicita, Reserva = aquele que só reserva e Conclusão = aquele que concluí a solicitação. Porém 1 Funcionário fará uma solicitação no sistema, depois um outro funcionário, ou o mesmo, fará a reserva do leito, quando o leito reservado for ocupado, outro funcionário ou o mesmo fará a Conclusão da solicitação. Ou seja, em 1 solicitação terei que informar 3 funcionários. Se foi esse seu racioncínio me perdoe por não estar entendendo.

Comment: Em nenhum momento existe esta limitação, vou reescrever a reposta para tentar ficar mais claro.